# ANDROID : How can i achieve Listview similar to 'today in history' app?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to developer app to show event as "today in history", i want to build UI like timeline listview like this image, please let me know if there is any way or library related to this.
Thanks in advance

[image: How to achieve listview like this]

I am done with this, upto now, but how to hide listitem divider

[image: I am done with this]

Comment: what you have tried so far?
post your xml for listview item and your output.

Comment: Looks pretty smart. I would imagine each item in the list view has a "left side" and a "right side". Left side is the circle + a 9-patch where the right side is again a textview with a nine patch as a background. the two layers are separated with a margin and the background of the listview item itself (+ the listview) is semi-transparent. I don't think it's doing anything extra clever but the usage of the available functionalities to achieve this is very nicely done.

Comment: @MohammadKhatri I have created Custom listview layout containing one Circle (with verticle line) image background on left side  & text view on right side, but it wont help me, because verticle line attached to that circle looks separated.

Comment: @pawarrohit14 look above comment of kha , it has all you want. and don't use any deviders so it'll not be saperated as you stated.

Comment: ok , thanks, Let me try and get back to you, btw thanks a lot :)

Comment: @kha Nearly perfect solution. To be perfect, just make the circle and the 9 patch **a single unit** (an ingeniously designed 9 patch).

Comment: how to hide the divider or make divider height zero?

Answer (score 1):

Apply a transparent background to your divider, your ListView layout should look similar to this.

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```